# Re entry tournament rules

Tags: tournament

When you re enter a tournament, do you have to post the big blind or can you wait until you are in the big blind position?

Answer (score 4):

A tournament shouldn't have you posting a big blind, unless you are in the big blind ever. When you re-buy you are treated as a new player, and depending on the tournament size you should also get a new seat card. When you re-buy, unless you are coming into a seat on the Small Blind(which you will sit out a hand) or the Big Blind(you will of course post your BB), otherwise you get your cards and play as normal.

Answer (score 4):

A Re-Entry tournament allows busted players to buy back into the tournament. You start again from scratch as if you were a *completely new player*. Therefore, you :

- leave the table.
- go to cashier buy another stack of chips.
- come back (move) to another table.

Unless a special rule/ruling applies(*), you would be assigned a new seat on another table and wait until you reach BB position (ie: [WSOP 2016 rules / #13](https://www.wsop.com/2016/2016%20wsop%20tournament%20rules.pdf)).

*Re-entry is not a re-buy, where you stay at the same table, and can carry on.* (see @`Grinch91` answer for more details about blinds)

(*) Once, in a satellite tournament I played (step 2 / 27 players left), a busted player immediately called for a re-entry. Before cards were dealt, dealer called TD, who then allowed the player to remain seated at the table, and play, as it was the only seat available (3 tables of 9). Nonetheless, this player had to wait for the BB to be dealt in again.